# difficult probability question - biased coin

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

Exercise 2 We have a biased coin that lands on tails 1/3 of the time and heads
2/3 of the time. We toss it until we get a sequence of 2 consecutive heads or a
sequence of 2 consecutive tails. What is the probability of getting 2 consecutive
heads before 2 consecutive tails? (Hint: We can condition on the first toss).

Comment: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ denote the event of seeing two consecutive heads before two consecutive tails, and denote by $X_k$ the result of toss $k$.

Let $p_1=P(A|X_1=H)$ and $p_2=P(A|X_1=H)$.
Then conditioning on $X_2$ gives $$p_1=(2/3)+(1/3)p_2$$
and $$p_2=(2/3)p_1 \,,$$
so $p_1=6/7$ and $p_2=4/7$.
Thus
$$P(A)=(2/3)p_1+(1/3)p_2=\frac{16}{21} \,.$$